# Change border color of multiple cells in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, border

While it is easy to change the font color and fill color of multiple cells at once in Excel 2010, I can't find a way to do this with border colors. Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't universally change the border color as you can with fill color. (In spite of the few answers that attempt to claim otherwise.) Why this is the case is beyond me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just multiselect the cells and click the borders button o the Main Tab.  On the menu, select Line color and have at it.

**edit**

Forgot about the obvious answer.  Format Painter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't work for me though. It changes the line color for future border changes, but it does nothing to the border color of the selected cells. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to reapply the border, because it is possible to apply a different color to each side. . .

Comment: So the answer is "no" then right? Because you cannot select multiple cells and change the color of all existing border to, say, red. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, should of gone with the obvious answer.  I edited it.

Comment: The answer is yes - change the line colour, then apply the borders you want (eg all outside borders, or just bottom or whatever you want)

Comment: This does not work as I cannot change border colour to anything that is different than gridlines colour specified under the File>Options>Advanced>Gridlines color. I wonder why is the colour option in there if it in fact, doesn't work?

Comment: Format painter is going to be just as tedious unless your border locations are the same in every single cell.

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer, found it myself, On the menu, select Line color, then you'll see a pencil, click on a cell then press ctrl and drag the pencil trough the desired cells. Check it by yourself !

Comment: That only changes the color of *one single border* via click, dragging with the pencil is actually just draws new borders.

Comment: Tried it, works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but it may help others.

1. Select the cells you want to have a border.
2. Right click in the highlighted cell area.
3. Select "Format Cells".
4. Click on the "Border" tab.
5. Underneath the "Line Style" you will see the option for "Color" which will affect your selected cells.

The steps above are how I create ALL of my borders when I am creating forms. Once you play with it a couple of minutes, it becomes second nature and is very quick and easy. Hope this helps!

PS - I should also mention that this works for Excel 2007, but it has been the same for previous versions so I will assume it is the same for the 2010 version, or at least very close.

Answer (score -2):

Press **alt H B I** and select the border color you like. The Excel sheet will show odd dots over the page. Just press **Esc** and border whatever content in the usual manner.

The default color of your borders would have changed to the one you had selected.

This will remain as your default border color until you close the Excel sheet.

To return back to the default "Black color", repeat the above step and choose "Black" color.

Comment: this doesn't work.  please check your Answer

Answer (score -2):

It **can** be done:

- File
- Options
- Advanced
- Scroll down to "Display options for this worksheet"
- Gridline color
- Choose your color

**ALL** gridlines that you previously applied will change to the new color at once, **WITHOUT** losing your gridline formatting!

Amy

Source:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/864-excel-change-border-color.html#way1